# Update User's first name and last name in principal

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I am updating user's information like **first name** and **last name** and I am getting first name and last name in all the pages for **welcome message**.

I have two controllers one for **ajax** request mapping and the other for **normal** request mapping.

Normal request mapping controller have this method. In this controller all page navigation is present and some request mapping which are not ajax calls

```
private String getPrincipalDisplay() {
    GreenBusUser user = null;
            String userName = "";
            Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

            if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
                user = (GreenBusUser) principal;
                userName = user.getFirstName() + " " + user.getLastName();
            } else {
                userName = "";
            }
            return userName;
}
```

This is how I am getting the **username** on every page by return string of this function I am adding it in **ModelMap object**.

When I **update user's information** I am doing in ajax request mapping.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/restify/updateUserData",  method = RequestMethod.PUT, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public ServiceResponse forgotPassword(@RequestBody Object user)
    {   
        //logger.debug("getting response");
        return setDataPut("http://localhost:7020/forgotPassword",user);
    }
```

user is an **Object** type which has **json** data. Now how do I retrieve data from object and update my ***first name and last name in principal***.

This is my **GreenBusUser** class

```
public class GreenBusUser  implements UserDetails
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    public GreenBusUser(String username,String password,Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority>  authorities,String firstName, String lastName)
    {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.grantedAuthorities = authorities;
        this.firstName=firstName;
        this.lastName=lastName;

        this.grantedAuthorities.stream().forEach(System.out::println);

    }

    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities()
    {
        return grantedAuthorities;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getPassword()
    {
        return password;
    }

    public String getUsername()
    {
        return username;
    }

    public boolean isAccountNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isAccountNonLocked()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:::::**

I have updated your code and applied some part of your answer into mine but still I ran into a problem

```
@RequestMapping(value="/updateUser",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String updateUser(ModelMap model) {

        UserInfo user = getUserObject();
        GreenBusUser newGreenBususer = null;
        List<User> list = new ArrayList<User>();


        list = FetchDataService.fetchDataUser("http://localhost:8060/GetuserbyUserName?username=" + getPrincipal(), user.getUsername(), user.getPassword());
        logger.debug("new user list ----->>>"+list.size());
        User newuser=(User)list.get(0);
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                   SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal(), SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getCredentials());

        Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        newGreenBususer=(GreenBusUser)principal;

        logger.debug("newGreenBususerDetails---->>>"+newGreenBususer.toString());

        newGreenBususer.setFirstName(newuser.getFirstName());
        newGreenBususer.setLastName(newuser.getLastName());

        if(newGreenBususer.getFirstName()!=null) {
            logger.debug("got my first name");
        }
        if(newGreenBususer.getLastName()!=null) {
            logger.debug("got my last name");
        }

        auth.setDetails(newGreenBususer);       
        SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        context.setAuthentication(auth);
        SecurityContextHolder.setContext(context);
        model.addAttribute("user", getPrincipalDisplay());
        model.addAttribute("userData", list);
        model.addAttribute("check", true);
        return "GreenBus_updateProfile_User";
    }
```

At first it sets the **firstname and lastname to GreenBusUser** and then there is **setDetails** method when I reload the page it says **No user found** when I am calling **getUserObject()** method at the top of this method.

```
private X2CUser getUserObject() {
        X2CUser userName = null;
        Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

        if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
            userName = ((X2CUser) principal);
        } else {
            logger.info("No user found");

        }
        return userName;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code .. It might help you.

```
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authReq = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, pass);
Authentication auth = authManager.authenticate(authReq);
SecurityContext sc = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
securityContext.setAuthentication(auth);
```

Comment: Atul I dont want to update my user name and pass only the first name and last name

Comment: Yes, once you set the firstnmae, lastname in DB, pass the username, password to db fetch the details and set that auth object to security context

Comment: ok so what do I pass in user and pass as parameters then? you are not getting I am not changing username or password rather first name and last name and I dont see in your answer where you are setting first name and last name in GreenBusUser object(after adding setters)

Comment: The first 2 lines will help you to fetch the data from DB where you again authenticate the user. It will fetch the updated details like new first and last name.And the last line of code where you set the auth object which contains the details which you are looking for. No need to set them explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally resolved my problem though I have later added some code in my question part in UPDATE section.

```
 Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        newGreenBususer=(GreenBusUser)principal;


        newGreenBususer.setFirstName(newuser.getFirstName());
        newGreenBususer.setLastName(newuser.getLastName());
```

Yes that's all need to be done.

This part--->>

```
    auth.setDetails(newGreenBususer);       
    SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    context.setAuthentication(auth);
    SecurityContextHolder.setContext(context);
```

set new context making security pointing to **null** when I reload still not clear because I am setting the details **before** reload so its like I get **new context** but I have set the new user details.

*Though I have finally resolved my problem but if anyone could shed some light why it was happening then I will accept his/her answer.*

**Thanks alot for your support. Keep Learning!**

Answer (score -1):

If you are updating the password, then it will be good to logout the user and tell him to relogin.

Comment: No suppose I have updated just the firstname and lastname then please tell me in that case