# Updated password not picked up after InMemoryUserDetailsManager updateUser call

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security

Hi I have a Rest WS using WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter to implement HTTP Basic auth.
The password is allowed to be updated and I need to let the WS to pick up updated password without restarting server
Following are the codes:

SecurityConfig

```
// init a user with credentials admin/password
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                        //disable csrf
                        .csrf().disable()
                        //authentic all requests
                        .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic()
                        //disable session
                        .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(inMemoryUserDetailsManager());
    }

    @Bean
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager inMemoryUserDetailsManager() {
        Properties users = new Properties();
        users.put("admin", "password,USER,enabled");
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(users);
    }
}
```

The controller that will update password

```
@RestController
public class someController{
    @Autowired
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager inMemoryUserDetailsManager;

    // update password from password -> pass
    @RequestMapping(...)
    public updatePass(){
        ArrayList<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthoritiesList = new ArrayList<>();
        grantedAuthoritiesList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER"));

        this.inMemoryUserDetailsManager.updateUser(new User("admin", "pass", grantedAuthoritiesList));
    }

    // another way that also doesn’t work
    @RequestMapping(...)
    public newUpdate(){
        ArrayList<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthoritiesList = new ArrayList<>();
        grantedAuthoritiesList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER"));    
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("admin", "pass",
                        grantedAuthoritiesList);

        SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        context.setAuthentication(auth);
        SecurityContextHolder.setContext(context);
    }
}
```

After calling updatePass() with credential admin/password for the first time, I can see that the password has been updated to "pass" in debugger

[image]

I assume that if I'm to call updatePass() again, I should use **admin/pass**. However it turned out to be still using the old **admin/password**.

Sources I referred to when writing this code [source1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25869260/how-can-i-add-users-to-the-inmemoryauthentication-builder-after-it-has-been-buil) [source2](https://javainterviewpoint.com/spring-security-inmemoryuserdetailsmanager/)

*I'm using Advance Rest Client to make the calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using SecurityContext, I overwrote function loadUserByUsername of interface UserDetailsService to let spring security always pick up the latest pwd from DB.

Answer (score 0):

When you update the password, you have to set the UserDetails in springSecurityContext object if the user is authenticated.

Comment: could you give more details regarding your answer? thanks in advance

Comment: This is the thing for which I am talking about, once you got the auth object update it;s details and set it again with new one:     SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    context.setAuthentication(auth);
    SecurityContextHolder.setContext(context);

Comment: I followed your way and created new function newUpdate() but it's still not picking up the new pwd. Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: Whenever you update anything in UserDetails then you have to set/create it in auth object and set it into the SecurityCOntext object.

Comment: Thanks @Atul, that’s what I did in the new function newUpdate() but it still doesn’t work. Could you take a look pls?

Comment: See this, this might helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50621118/update-users-first-name-and-last-name-in-principal/50639739#50639739

Answer (score 0):

in my case, `SecurityConfig.java` is defined in same level pacakge as `SpringBootApplication.java`, since `@ComponentScan` default tells Spring to [scan current package and sub-packages](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-component-scanning#component-scan-default), so `SecurityConfig` is not scanned. after configure `@ComponentScan` [scan specific package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69272345/how-to-configure-componentscan-to-scan-specific-packages-and-get-single-classes) of `SecurityConfig`, issue is solved.